# Populate select options from an array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this API call that returns types of Pokemon as in:

```
["Grass", "Poison", "Fire", "Flying", "Water", "Bug", "Normal", "Electric", "Ground", "Fighting", "Psychic", "Rock", "Ice", "Ghost", "Dragon"]
```

This is a result of a function that takes all Pokemon values and filters out duplicates and such. The same function is used to take these values and populate the select options:

```
  let pokemonSingleType = (() => {
    let types = pokemonData.reduce((acc, { type }) => (acc.push(...type), acc), [])
    types = new Set(types);
    types = [...types];
    console.log(types);
    return <option>
      {types}
    </option>
  })();
```

That gets rendered below:

```
 <select value={searchType} onChange={updateSearchByType.bind(this)} 
  className="formcontrol" id="typeSelect">
  {pokemonSingleType}
</select>
```

The issue is that I get the whole array as one Select option value. Please see image below:

The output is as below:

[image]

Also, when I do a for loop before, it stops at the first iteration:

```
let pokemonSingleType = (() => {
    let types = pokemonData.reduce((acc, { type }) => (acc.push(...type), acc), [])
    types = new Set(types);
    types = [...types];
    for(let i =0; i< types.length; i++){
      return <option>
      {types[i]}
    </option>
    }
    
  })();
```

Comment: Your loop stops because you're using a return statement inside it, push option elements in an array instead and then return it

Answer (score 0):

`<option>` tags should be placed around *each* element, not all of them. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is the most direct way to accomplish this:

```js
const Dropdown = ({options}) =>
  <select>
    {options.map((e, i) => <option key={i}>{e}</option>)}
  </select>
;

const pokemon = ["Grass", "Poison", "Fire", "Flying", "Water", "Bug", "Normal", "Electric", "Ground", "Fighting", "Psychic", "Rock", "Ice", "Ghost", "Dragon"];

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<Dropdown options={pokemon} />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

For the second example, `return` inside the loop will only return the first element. You could push the JSX elements onto an array and return that, but this still seems like a lot of indirection.

In both examples, using `reduce` to spread each element in an array onto an array accumulator is an antipattern; `map` does this best.